# how can git checkout HEAD~2 go 10 commits back

Tags: git, git-checkout

There's a remote branch `my-issue-branch` and a local branch of the same name. We performed

`git pull --rebase`

to get the latest commits locally, but the two last commits are breaking the build. We want to go 2 commits back to build the project and do

`git checkout HEAD~2`

which takes us about 10 commits back, instead of just two.

Only

`git checkout <commit-hash>`

helps the situation.

Keeping in mind, that four people work on this branch, what can be wrong?

Comment: What does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` tell you?  It's likely that it's going so many commits back due to previous branches being merged in.

Comment: I thought so, I will go back to my workstation tomorrow and take a look at git log --graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified diagram:

```
...--o--*-----o------o--o   <-- you are here
         \          /
          o--o--o--o
```

You are at the marked commit, towards the right.  You need to walk to the `*` commit towards the left, following one or the other lines, or maybe even following both at the same time.  How many `o`s will you traverse?  How many `o`s are there "between" commit `*` and the right hand edge one?

Now consider what happens with Git when there are merge commits (you must have some near the tip of your current branch, to be seeing this).  The `~2` count walks back two commits *on some particular line*.  What about all the commits on the *other* lines?  What happens to them?

Comment: Can this be avoided by using rebase instead of merge? Also how do I explicitly tell git what line to follow?

Comment: When you rebase *your* commits you will discard merges from your rebased work, but that won't affect merges you bring in from other people. You could rebase *their* work, but that's not very nice to them :-) (seriously, it's OK to do this *if* everyone agrees to it in advance, but know that it makes extra work for everyone—be sure the benefits you are buying are worth the cost you are paying). To follow different lines you can either specify an explicit walk a la https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html or just view the graph (`git log --graph`) and [continued]

Comment: ... and then check out by explicit commit hash. Normally, though, for tracking down where a bug is introduced, you should see if you can use `git bisect`, which is a higher level process that obviates the need to manually dig around in the graph.